# Identify a story of carving half chair logo on Moon

Tags: story-identification, tv

Very long ago, I watched a cartoon. It's not in my mind whether it was telefilm or an episode of a TV series. Here are details I remember:

- The main character (probably a villian) I remember was *chair-headed* meaning his head was chair and rest of his body was of human.
- It was his special birthday party (probably, 25th or something) when someone bring the idea of making the birthday memorable.
- The idea was to carve his logo and name on the Moon.
- They started the process using a very powerful laser fired directly from Earth.
- But, someone (probably, a superhero or cops) interrupted and the project failed.
- In the end, during credit scene, the Moon was displayed with half chair logo.

Can you please identify this telefilm or TV show?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*[The Tick](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112196/)*. That's [Chairface Chippendale](http://tick.wikia.com/wiki/Chairface_Chippendale), episode 7, ["The Moon Menace"](http://tick.wikia.com/wiki/The_Tick_7:_The_Moon_Menace?veaction=edit&redlink=1)

[image: Chairface]

And yes, for all of the subsequent episodes, they kept the damage:

[image: Defaced moon]

Comment: Wow. That fast. What's *The Tick*? TV series or telefilm?

Comment: :) He's a very distinctive character. It's a cartoon TV series. There was a live-action version a few years later.

Comment: My first thought upon seeing the title was, "like in *the Tick?*" It was a comic book originally, and then a cartoon. Both are worth checking out.

Comment: BTW, _The Tick_ comic book was created, written, and drawn by Ben Edlund, who's currently a writer on _Gotham_, and who wrote the "Jaynestown" episode of _Firefly_.  Just thought someone should mention that.

Comment: How was he going to fit the rest of his name on?

Comment: @Richard: Smaller letters?

Answer (score 1):

An almost identical plot was used in the "Lasers in the Night" episode of "GI Joe, A Real American Hero" in 1985. Cobra Commander used lasers to carve the nearside of the moon to look like his face...er...helmet. He was defeated, mostly because his subordinates thought it was a stupid idea and walked off. At the end, the moon was recarved to look like normal.